# AirflowException: The conn_id `http_default` isn't defined error trying to run an HTTP operator in Airflow

Tags: python, http, airflow

I have an Airflow DAG that, as the last task, needs to send an HTTP request to trigger a Google Cloud Function. I am testing it out but the HTTP task fails.

Task definition:

```
send_standby_signal = ho.SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id = 'send-k8s-cluster-standby-signal',
        endpoint = 'https://path-to-function-endpoint', 
        method = 'POST',
        data = '',
        trigger_rule = trigger_rule.TriggerRule.ALL_DONE
)
```

Error:

```
[2019-10-02 13:57:29,088] {http_operator.py:87} INFO - Calling HTTP method
[2019-10-02 13:57:29,122] {__init__.py:1580} ERROR - The conn_id `http_default` isn't defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 1441, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/http_operator.py", line 92, in execute
    self.extra_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/hooks/http_hook.py", line 101, in run
    session = self.get_conn(headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/hooks/http_hook.py", line 60, in get_conn
    conn = self.get_connection(self.http_conn_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/hooks/base_hook.py", line 80, in get_connection
    conn = random.choice(cls.get_connections(conn_id))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/hooks/base_hook.py", line 75, in get_connections
    conns = cls._get_connections_from_db(conn_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 73, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/hooks/base_hook.py", line 58, in _get_connections_from_db
    "The conn_id `{0}` isn't defined".format(conn_id))
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: The conn_id `http_default` isn't defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer, really. I didn't have `http_default` defined in Airflow Connections. How embarrassing.

Comment: I defined the connection in airflow UI, but I am still facing the same problem. Looking for solution.

Comment: Same issue for me, connection is defined on Airflow UI, but DAG is not able to access it... Strange :(

Comment: For automated testing purposes, creating a connection via the UI isn't really practical. Is there a way to programmatically create a connection for test environments?